# How plausible is the Skylon project?

Tags: propulsion, ssto, sabre-engine

Skylon is the frontier of launch vehicle research with literally 1 TRL(Technology Readiness Level), and it is more difficult than the Space Shuttle project. The project would cost estimate of 12 billion dollars, and the development of SABRE is only at the beginning. With heavy competition of other companies, (SpaceX have just launched their reused boosters), is it just a matter of time that this project would be cancelled?

Comment: Is this about the plausibility of the technology or the feasibility of the business?

Comment: @Schlusstein in fact both, if there is no business, the technology itself would be cancelled automatically.

Comment: that doesn't mean it wouldn't have worked though

Comment: Raze and @Schlusstein I dont think that Galactic Virgin, Blue Origin, SpaceX etc. have any bearing on the continued development of the SABRE.  If fact if it is not mentioned anywhere here I will dig out the link that DARPA/USAF are pushing it forward as well as the UK/EU.

Comment: TRL is not 1. generally considered to have moved from 2/3 to 4/5 before 2015

Answer (score 4):

It's plausible enough that companies like BAE Systems and organizations like ESA have invested in the technology. BAE Systems' interest lies in defence applications of the SABRE engine, so we'll probably see those long before Skylon gets off the ground.

Comment: You may find this link useful "US Military Set to Unveil Concepts Based on Skylon Space Plane Tech" - http://www.space.com/32115-skylon-space-plane-engines-air-force-vehicle.html - I would also add, that the SABRE engine brings something to the table that no one else is bringing at this time.  Access to space for all Humans, think age and physical conditioning. This aspect is critical to Humans in Space.